# Map for browser-based Games

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a bit trouble here with creating a map for a browser based game like Travian. I have created a function which drags the map into different directions, but each time I click on a different position than where I released the mouse on it directly changes position and then I can move it as I want. Is there any way of solving this? Is JQuery needed? (I'm not so good at Javascript so my code might be a bit different than what the easy way around code would look like)

Full document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //object of the element to be moved
        _item = null;

        //stores x & y co-ordinates of the mouse pointer
        mouse_x = 0;
        mouse_y = 0;

        // stores top,left values (edge) of the element
        mapdiv_x = 0;
        mapdiv_y = 0;

        //bind the functions
        function move_init()
        {
            document.onmousemove = _move;
            document.onmouseup = _stop;
        }

        //destroy the object when we are done
            function _stop()
        {
            _item = null;
        }

        //main functions which is responsible for moving the element (div in our example)
        function _move(e)
        {
            mouse_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("mapdiv").backgroundPositionX;
            mouse_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("mapdiv").backgroundPositionY;
            if(_item != null)
            { 
                _item.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (mouse_x - mapdiv_x) + "px -" + (mouse_y - mapdiv_y) + "px";
            }
        }

        //will be called when use starts dragging an element
        function _move_item(mapdiv)
        {
            //store the object of the element which needs to be moved
            _item = mapdiv;
            mouse_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("mapdiv").backgroundPositionX;
            mouse_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("mapdiv").backgroundPositionY;

            oldmapdivx = _item.style.backgroundPositionX;
            oldmapdivy = _item.style.backgroundPositionY;

            mapdiv_x = oldmapdivx - mouse_x;
            mapdiv_y = oldmapdivy - mouse_y;

            mapdivx2 = mouse_x - mapdiv_x;
            mapdivy2 = mouse_y - mapdiv_y;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #mapdiv {
        background-image:url('images/map.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-color:#666;
        width:750px;
        height:500px;
        cursor: move;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="move_init()">
    <div id="mapdiv" onmousedown="_move_item(this);"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never NEED JQuery, it's written in JavaScript so you could always recreate what it give you. But why would you want to since it makes life so much easier; you probably WANT JQuery. It's a great tool, and if you're just starting out in JS it'll save you tons of pain down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see the issue in your code, unfortunately.

If you're not dead set on writing your own code for this, though, there is actually a really nice Jquery plugin that does exactly what you seem to want. It's called Overscroll (http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll) and provides you with all the features you'd need for a system like this. Give it a look, I've found it really useful in my own work in the past. Looking through the code might also help you find the issue in your own solution, as well.